# Place decorative pictures on left and right side of my webpage

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to embrace my website with images on both sides like this (this shows the users browser window):
[image]
(pardon the gimp skills...)

I want the main content to get smaller with smaller window size.

Anyway, so far I've [tried this (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/RxyAW/14/):

HTML:

```
<div id="everything" class="container">
  <div id="left" class="container side-image-left"></div>
  <div class="container  main ">
    ... header logo etc ...
    <div class="container content">
      ...
    </div>
    ... footer etc ...
  </div>
  <div id="right" class="container side-image-right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#everything {
    /*
    this was my temporary try for the red divs in my image, 
    just a static, nonadjusting background with width 1366px.

    background-image: url('../images/bg_everything.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-y;*/
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1366px;
}

.side-image-left, .side-image-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    width: 125px;
    height: 100px;
}
.side-image-right {
    right: 0;
}
.main {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1116px;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

The problems with it:

- The divs on the side stick to the content, but as soon as the browser window gets too small, they to the browser window instead
- I have a second "content" .container in the "main" .container, which, when resizing, makes small "jumps". The main container background should never be shown, but during these "jumps" there's some empty space on both sides. Better to view on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RxyAW/14/).

So, how can I get the desired behaviour as shown in the picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this by doing this:

HTML

```
<div id="bgfix">
    <div id="main">
        <div id="leftbg"></div>
        <div id="rightbg"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#bgfix {
    min-width: /* main width (1116px in this case) */;
    height: 100%; 

    overflow-x: hidden;

    background-image: /* main background url */;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

#main {
    width: 1116px;

    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#leftbg {
    position: absolute;
    width: /* image width */;
    background-image: /* image url */;

    left: /* -(image width) */;
}

#rightbg {
    /* same as leftbg */
    right: /* -(image width) */; /* except use right instead of left */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use centered `background-image` placed on the `body`.

To make your images responsive, use -

```
background-size: contain;
```

Answer (score 0):

use a new class "set"

```
<div id="everything" class="container">
  <div id="left" class="set container side-image-left"></div>
  <div class="set container  main ">
    ... header logo etc ...
    <div class="container content">
      ...
    </div>
    ... footer etc ...
  </div>
  <div id="right" class=" set container side-image-right"></div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.set{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Did you try this? It looks like this with your suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/RxyAW/17/